# How to change the product variation auto title pattern in drupal 7 commerce?

Tags: 7, commerce, entities

Update

Got it working with [Automatic Entity Label](https://www.drupal.org/project/auto_entitylabel)

---

Is it possible to provide a token pattern, just like for the SKU auto generation, for the auto generation of product variation titles? I can only check if they shall be autocompleted, which they should, but their title is always just like the node title.

How can you define/ alter this?

Comment: Commerce doesn't have that functionality to the best of my knowledge, so presumably you're using a contrib module to provide it? If so which one?

Comment: autoSKU, its a contrib module yes. I've just managed it with auto entity labels module :)